# Not being able to print a simple nested if condition's result on the console

Tags: c

This is a simple test program where I am trying to get the result "12 angry men" shown on the console after I complete taking inputs to get into the sub genre from the 2nd `printf` of the program. what have i done wrong here? please don't try to find relevance with anything here. The console will simply ask the user to press 1 for action then it'd ask Humorous/Other, when humorous would show 12 angry men after taking input as 1.1.

```
int main()
{
    int action=1,comedy=2;
    float humorous=1.1, other=1.2,input1;
    int input;
    printf("Which Movies You Want to See\n");
    printf("Action/Comedy");
    scanf("%d",&input);
    if(input==1)
    {
        printf("Humorous/Other");
        scanf("%f",&input1);

        if(input1==1.1)
        {
            printf("12 angry men");    
        }
    }

    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: Using floating points for input here seems like a really bad plan as [floating point values can be really strange](https://floating-point-gui.de). You'll also want to use `switch` (don't forget the `break;`) to break out choices instead of a long, convoluted chain of `if` statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like others have mention, it is not good practice to directly compare floats like you are trying to do. For example, if you set `int input1 = 1.1` and then try to use `printf("%f", input1)`, the output is `1.10000` or something similar. This will not return true for `1.1 == 1.10000` in C at run time which is what is causing the issue.

You could just use different integers to case into what you want to happen depending on the input, or (if you really, really must) you can compare using the `<` and `>` operators. Ie `if (input1 > 1.09 && input1 < 1.11)`.

This will give you the desired result.

Comment: Except that 1.1 and 1.10000 _are equal_.  So while your point is valid, your explanation is unconvincing.

Comment: intuitively, yes they are equal but not in C at run time which was the point.

Comment: no, they are the same.  There is a difference between 1.1 and 1.1f which is what is happening here.  You are probably confusing how a function such as printf presents floating point values, and the actual stored value. Two _different_ but close values may be presented as the same value.  I understand what you are trying to say, but it is inaccurate and confusing, so does not make your argument well.

Comment: Moreover, the unadorned %f format specifier will not print trailing zeros.  The problem here is that the implicit conversion of the float value 1.1 to double does not necessarily generate precisely the same value as the literal double 1.1.  printf( "%.15f %.15f", (double)input1, 1.1) might produce a more convincing exemplar.

Comment: I understand how the conversion from a float value to the constant of 1.1 is not exactly the same value and causes issues when trying to compare them primitively, but did not explain that very well and may have caused my answer to imply otherwise. thanks for a good explanation!

Comment: The test I suggested yields 1.100000023841858 1.100000000000000. float has approximately 6 significant digits(decimal) precision, while double is good for 15.

Answer (score 0):

You should never test a *binary* floating-point number for *exact* equality to a *decimal* real value.  A 32-bit float can represent a finite number of discrete values few of which coincide with an exact decimal value die to the binary rather then decimal floating-point encoding.

It is probably a bad idea to to floating point values for "menu selection" in any event, but if you insist, your code can be fixed thus:

```
if( fabs(input1 - 1.1) < 0.01 )
```

It also happens to work if you avoid the unnecessary implicit conversion from `float` to `double`:

```
if( input1 == 1.1f )
```

but that is still ill-advised in general - it will not work for all values.

Answer (score 0):

You want to compare floats, so you want to do the following:

```
if(input1==1.1f)
{
    /* Will be true if the user inputs 1.1 */
}
```

and not

```
if(input1==1.1){}
```

Comment: would also need to change scanf to `scanf("%.1f", &input1);` as well if this route is taken

Comment: Works for me without chaning the scanf @Jamie Taylor Sangerman

Comment: @GlitchInTheMatrix : "working" does not make it a good idea - you really need to understand why it worked, to understand the limitations of the solution and why you might want to avoid it.  https://floating-point-gui.de/